# Toggle Searchbar View using UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uisearchbar

[image: Search Bar]

I have a search bar embedded above a tableview which is visible as soon as the view is opened i want it to be hidden when the page loads and on click of the search button (Bottom left corner) **i want the searchbar to get animated from top**. I have read that this can be done using UIScrollview, but none of the tutorials have been able to help me.

Comment: i want the searchbar to Scroll into view? can you please explain this

Comment: I want to set the searchbar to drop from above and become visible

Comment: For that you have to animate from top its not scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For

1)I want it to be hidden when the page loads and on click of the search button

In your search button clicked...

```
 if(self.searchBar.isHidden)
{
    [sender setSelected:YES];
    self.searchBar.hidden=NO;
    [self resetFrame:tableView toFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y+44, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height) withDelay:0.5];
}
else if(!self.searchBar.isHidden)
{
    [sender setSelected:NO];
    self.searchBar.hidden=YES;
    [self resetFrame:tableView toFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y-44, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height) withDelay:0.5];
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}


 -(void)resetFrame:(UIView *)view toFrame:(CGRect )frame withDelay:(float)delay
 {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:delay];
    [view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

Just add the above when you click search button or if want it to be hidden when page shows add it in the **viewWillAppear** method

2)i want the searchbar to get animated from top.

Add the searchbar to the view by making its y axis below 0 example -100 and once page loads set its actual frame  use **resetFrame** method to bring your search bar from top

Comment: i have done this but this shows a blank white space above the tableview when it is hidden which i dont want

Comment: you would have not set the tableview frame see my edited answer

Comment: try the above answer and share results